# Dynamic Link in Redirect of GenFireServerEvent

Tags: redirect

A little background: I have a list that collects data for a variety of issues -- application, database, network, etc.  They all have common information, but then there is specific information unique to each type.  I've set up a series of forms to collect the unique types of information based on the selection from a dropdown (application, database, network, etc.)  on the common information form, which will then direct them to the correct type of form after the hitting OK on the common information form.

From my research, it seems that the custom submit button using the GenFireServerEvent function was the best solution.  What I'm trying to do is grab the selected value from the dropdown and place it into the redirect URL of the GenFireServer event.

Here's what I've got so far: (this is without the variable)

```
<input id="custom" type="button" value="Save" name="btnSave" onclick="javascript:var getCurEvent=document.getElementById('ctl00_SPWebPartManager1_g_5c74d44e_a2ed_4ba7_bbf6_5d307eacf8b4_ff41_ctl00_DropDownChoice').value;alert(getCurEvent);{ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={../cc/ccr/Lists/Event Mgmt Log EML/NewForm.aspx}')}"/>
```

I put in the alert just to make sure I was getting the value, which I am.  But I've tried a number of methods to include the variable in the redirect URL and it never seems to work.  Ultimately the selected value should get placed right before NewForm.aspx ... and **then it should redirect to either ApplicationNewForm.aspx or DatabaseNewForm.aspx or NetworkNewForm.aspx ... depending on the selection in the dropdown.**

*I've unsuccesfully tried my hand at XSL variables and JQuery as solutions, based on readings online, I also tried using concat, but nothing has seemed to be the magic potion yet.*

I am definitely new to this side of SharePoint and this may be a dumb question, but I am generally not one to ask for help, I like to find the solution on my own... so IOW I'm pretty stuck!  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Steve